# Pass dataset attribute from anchor tag all the way down to bootstrap modal button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I have an `<a>` tag that toggles the show/hide of a `Bootstrap` `Modal`.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-foo=${FOO} data-target="#emailFoo"></a>
```

Where `emailFoo` `modal` looks like

```
<div class="modal fade" id="emailFoo">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="sendEmail">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to obtain the data of `FOO` upon the clicked `event` of an `#email` button inside the `#emailFoo`

**How can I get the value of the foo from the button that opened the modal in the #sendEmail click event?**

```
$( "#sendEmail" ).click(function() {
    //Get foo here from Parent modal that button is inside
     
    //$('#emailFoo').dataset['foo']
});
```

As a workaround I can obtain foo from when the modal is first opened. I was thinking I can then set this value somewhere else so that the button click can get it.

I.e.

```
    $('#emailFoo').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

        //This works! How can I do the same thing from the `sendEmail` click event above?
        const callerFromAnchorTag = $(e.relatedTarget);
        const foo = callerFromAnchorTag [0].dataset['foo'];
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you want to get the foo value in this way:

```
$( "#sendEmail" ).click(function() {

     const btn = $(this);
     
     const modal_id = btn.parents('.modal').attr('id');

     let toggler = $('body').find('[data-target="#' + modal_id +'"]');

     console.log(toggler.attr('data-foo'));
});
```

**UPDATE:**

new part:

so we have several toggler in a page, you want to detect witch toggler is the caller of modal?

A fancy way to achieve this (by js objects):

```
class Modal {
    constructor(selector) {
        this.$modal = $(selector);

        this.modal_id = this.$modal.attr('id');
        this.$toggler = null;

        this.init();
        this.events();
    }

    init() {
        const obj = this;
    }

    events() {
        const obj = this;

        $('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function () {
            const $a_toggler = $(this);
            if ($a_toggler.attr('data-target') === '#' + obj.modal_id)
                obj.$toggler = $(this);
        });
    }

    get_toggler() {
        return this.$toggler;
    }
}
```

usage:

making new modal object (at first of your code):

`const my_modal = new Modal($('#emailFoo'));`

returning toggler jquery object (wherever you want to get it):

`console.log(my_modal.get_toggler());`

**another simple way:**

make a hidden input inside your modal like this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-foo=${FOO} data-target="#emailFoo" data-toggler="toggler-1"></a>
<div class="modal fade" id="emailFoo">
    <input type="hidden" class="js-toggler__input" value="" hidden>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="sendEmail">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

after clicking on togglers, save its `id` or some attribute like `data-toggler="__toggler-number__"` (I used data attribute):

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function () {
    const toggler = $(this);
    const toggler_identifier = toggler.attr('data-toggler');
    let modal_id = toggler.attr('data-target');
    $(modal_id).find('.js-toggler__input').val(toggler_identifier);
});
```

so you can get the toggler by jQuery:

```
let toggler_identifier = $("#sendEmail").parents('.modal').find('.js-toggler__input').val();
console.log($('[data-toggler="' + toggler_identifier + '"]'))
```

be care about:

`data-toggler` attributes should be unique

some points:

better to use classes over data-attributes to select DOM, data-attributes should use to store little data.

Comment: The `find('[data-target=` is what I was looking for. thanks. Unfortunately, I have edge cases where `toggler` is a button that can exist on multiple different `tr`s and pass along multiple different `foo`s (All done through templating)

In fact, each `tr` already has a reference to `foo` and so I could even forget about `toggler`. So I'm actually looking for something like `"find the tr that this modal opened up from (via toggler button)"`

Comment: so we have several toggler in a page, you want to detect witch toggler is the caller of modal?

Comment: That's correct!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead assign foo to button data-attr

```
$('#emailFoo').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    const callerFromAnchorTag = $(e.relatedTarget);
    const foo = callerFromAnchorTag [0].dataset['foo'];
    $('#sendEmail').attr('data-foo', foo);
});
```

then

```
$('#sendEmail').click(function(){
    const foo = $(this).data('foo');
});
```

Comment: Where is `e` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Ali works, but you can try this too:

1. Add a hidden field in the modal: `<input type="hidden" id="hidden-value">`
2. On clicking the modal toggle, set the value of this `hidden-value`:

   ```
    $('#open-modal').on('click', function(event) {
        $('#hidden-value').val($(this).data('foo'));
    });
   ```
3. On clicking the **OK** button, get the value (just logging here):

   ```
    $( "#sendEmail" ).on('click', function() {
        console.log($('#hidden-value').val());
    });
   ```

This is an answer more on the way of 'set the value somewhere, then get it on click'.